# Four Yearling badges within 20 days

Tags: support, badges

I thought that the [Yearling badge](//tex.stackexchange.com/badges/13/yearling) is awarded once a year for members who earn 200+ reputation in that year. But I was awarded this badge four times within last 20 days.

So how does it really work?

Comment: By chance did you come back after staying away many years?

Comment: I created the account five years before. But didn’t have sufficient reputation the initial years .

Comment: Maybe you earn >200 rep this year and they give you the yearling badge for the 5 years before, I don't know if it's correct or a bug :)

Comment: Are you afraid that you are aging too fast? ;-)

Comment: @marmot HaHa. Slightly ;)

Comment: [Here is a way out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423010/121799). Just board a very fast spacecraft, special relativity will do the rest. (No, this does not only work for ducks. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Will try once aging becomes too fast :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Yearling badge](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) is awarded for being an "Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation." However, it can be awarded *retroactively* if you've been around for a while but only recently started contributing. Here is a view of your reputation over time ([data](https://pastebin.com/JaYNPVkR)):

[image]

You triggered the Yearling badge on the following dates, based on your reputation change:

- May 17, 2014: Joined TeX.SE
- May 17, 2015: Been a member on TeX.SE for 1 year with reputation 178 (< 200); eligible for 1 Yearling badge
- May 17, 2016: Been a member on TeX.SE for 2 years with reputation 198 (< 200); eligible for 2 Yearling badges
- May 17, 2017: Been a member on TeX.SE for 3 years with reputation 198 (< 200); eligible for 3 Yearling badges
- May 24, 2017: Earned 10 daily rep to achieve 208 total reputation > First Yearling badge
- May 17, 2018: Been a member on TeX.SE for 4 years with reputation 228 (< 400); eligible for 4 Yearling badges
- Oct 28, 2018: Earned 130 daily rep to achieve 448 total reputation > Second Yearling badge (reputation > 400)
- Nov 10, 2018: Earned 114 daily rep to achieve 641 total reputation > Third Yearling badge (reputation > 600)
- Nov 16, 2018: Earned 137 daily rep to achieve 820 total reputation > Fourth Yearling badge (reputation > 800)
- Nov 18, 2018: Earned 200 daily rep to achieve 1,115 total reputation > Fifth Yearling badge (reputation > 1,000)

Reference: [How does the Yearling badge now work over multi years?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237081/168244)

Comment: So I understood it wrong. :)

Comment: @nidhin: Also see [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/168244)

Comment: Thanks for the link.